# How to make a view controller only appear the first time a user opens the app in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I have two problems.

How do I detect when a user has opened my app for the first time.

and

How do I change the initial view controller programatically so it opens the "tutorial" view controller the first time a user opens the app, and opens the "home" view controller all of the other times the user opens the app.

I have already created my storyboard, I have seen solutions where one must delete their entire storyboard but I don't want to do this because it will delete all of my previous work. If there is a solution without deleting the entire storyboard or with deleting the storyboard without deleting the contents inside the view controller that would also be acceptable.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: For the first part, check user defaults to see whether it contains a known key, such as "tutorialShown".  If there's no such key, show your tutorial and put the key into user defaults.  For the second, it's probably easiest to present the tutorial as a modal display over your home controller.

Answer (score 1):

you'd have to do this via code and not interface builder.

You do that in your app delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        let seenTutorial = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "SEEN-TUTORIAL")
        let rootViewController = seenTutorial ? UIViewController() : UITutorialViewController()
        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

Update your UserDefaults inside the tutorial controller whenever you feel it's a good place to update it:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "SEEN-TUTORIAL")
```

Answer (score 0):

what I usually do in situation like this:

- create initial screen that looks like your launch screen and in `viewDidAppear` determine whether onboarding on some other screen should be shown
- present this screen modally
- using `.plist` is suitable for storing a `Bool` value that represents whether the app has been ever launched, or onboarding completed